# Query for extract string from xml in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

In SQL Server 2012, I have a table  `DEFINITIONS` and a column in it that value of it is XML and name of column is "XML". I want to extract string "[CDATA[xxxx]]" from XML column (in parameter tag). how can I do that?

XML Example value:

```
<CatalogItem subType="0" type="82">
   <id>7c75be9f-d490-4ff5-81ed-064349f4efde</id>
   <name>Test White</name>
   <description />
   <attributes>0</attributes>
   <parameters>&lt;conditions&gt;&lt;condition grouping="or"&gt;&lt;prop-key&gt;usb_device_serial_number&lt;/prop-key&gt;&lt;op-key&gt;equals&lt;/op-key&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[gdefgd||]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/condition&gt;&lt;/conditions&gt;</parameters>
   <customParameterNames />
   <enforceProducts>
     <Product type="WIN" />
   </enforceProducts>
   </CatalogItem>
```

Update 1

This Query solve my problem:

```
if object_id('dbo.cdata') is not null drop table dbo.cdata;
create table dbo.cdata(
  x xml
);
insert into dbo.cdata(x)
  SELECT XML FROM [HQ-MC-SRV-01].[dbo].[DEFINITIONS]
select
  xv.v.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as cdata
from dbo.cdata
cross apply
  cdata.x.nodes(
   '//parameters'
  ) as pp(p)
cross apply (
  values(
   cast(pp.p.value(
     '.', 'nvarchar(max)'
   ) as xml)
  )
 ) as xp(p)
cross apply
 xp.p.nodes('//value') as xv(v)
;
```

Thanks a Lot, Andrei Odegov

Update 2

i have to extract "serialNumber" and "endUser" from this XML with previous query too.

```
<CatalogItem subType="0" type="93">
 <id>9d6825e6-fa89-44e1-8e0f-61768016624c</id>
 <name>tteesstt</name>
 <description />
 <attributes>0</attributes>
 <entries>
  <entry>
    <serialNumber>zsxxdx</serialNumber>
    <userType>user</userType>
    <endUser>farhad@drf.local</endUser>
    <description />
  </entry>
 </entries>
</CatalogItem>
```

Update 3

```
 <CatalogItem subType="0" type="12">
  <id>169d6139-bdb6-4fff-88e6-09f00dd2f155</id>
  <name>za</name>
  <description />
  <attributes>0</attributes>
  <SIDMode>true</SIDMode>
  <nameIdentificationType>1</nameIdentificationType>
  <entries>
   <entry>
    <name>farhad</name>
    <path>CN=farhad,CN=Users,DC=DCVLAB,DC=LOCAL</path>
    <uid>F7A84834EAC8984AA7FBEAD7A5539432</uid>
    <serverName>192.168.7.2</serverName>
    <sid>S-1-5-21-907365782-933549064-1582919620-1103</sid>
    <type>user</type>
   <entry>
    <name>IT-MNG</name>
    <path>CN=IT,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
    <uid>BEDC7DDF93A8D54DAC7A5CEE7307BF4F</uid>
    <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
    <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-1107</sid>
    <type>user</type>
   </entry>
  </entries>
 </CatalogItem>
```

Comment: You can post the query you are trying with to achieve your results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking into account your test data, you can try to adapt the following code:

```
declare @x xml = '
<CatalogItem subType="0" type="82">
   <id>7c75be9f-d490-4ff5-81ed-064349f4efde</id>
   <name>Test White</name>
   <description />
   <attributes>0</attributes>
   <parameters>&lt;conditions&gt;&lt;condition grouping="or"&gt;&lt;prop-key&gt;usb_device_serial_number&lt;/prop-key&gt;&lt;op-key&gt;equals&lt;/op-key&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[gdefgd||]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/condition&gt;&lt;/conditions&gt;</parameters>
   <customParameterNames />
   <enforceProducts>
     <Product type="WIN" />
   </enforceProducts>
   </CatalogItem>
';

select cast(@x.value('(//parameters)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') as xml).query('//value/text()') as cdata;
```

## Output

```
+----------+
|  cdata   |
+----------+
| gdefgd|| |
+----------+
```

## Update:

```
if object_id('dbo.cdata') is not null drop table dbo.cdata;

create table dbo.cdata(
  x xml
);

insert into dbo.cdata(x)
  values ('
<CatalogItem subType="0" type="82">
   <id>7c75be9f-d490-4ff5-81ed-064349f4efde</id>
   <name>Test White</name>
   <description />
   <attributes>0</attributes>
   <parameters>&lt;conditions&gt;&lt;condition grouping="or"&gt;&lt;prop-key&gt;usb_device_serial_number&lt;/prop-key&gt;&lt;op-key&gt;equals&lt;/op-key&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[gdefgd||]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[foo]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/condition&gt;&lt;/conditions&gt;</parameters>
   <parameters>&lt;conditions&gt;&lt;condition grouping="or"&gt;&lt;prop-key&gt;usb_device_serial_number&lt;/prop-key&gt;&lt;op-key&gt;equals&lt;/op-key&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[gdefgd||170]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[foo170]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/condition&gt;&lt;/conditions&gt;</parameters>
   <customParameterNames />
   <enforceProducts>
     <Product type="WIN" />
   </enforceProducts>
   </CatalogItem>
'), ('
<CatalogItem subType="0" type="82">
   <id>7c75be9f-d490-4ff5-81ed-064349f4efde</id>
   <name>Test White</name>
   <description />
   <attributes>0</attributes>
   <parameters>&lt;conditions&gt;&lt;condition grouping="or"&gt;&lt;prop-key&gt;usb_device_serial_number&lt;/prop-key&gt;&lt;op-key&gt;equals&lt;/op-key&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[gdefgd||42]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;value&gt;&lt;![CDATA[foo42]]&gt;&lt;/value&gt;&lt;/condition&gt;&lt;/conditions&gt;</parameters>
   <customParameterNames />
   <enforceProducts>
     <Product type="WIN" />
   </enforceProducts>
   </CatalogItem>
');

select
  xv.v.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as cdata
from dbo.cdata
cross apply
  cdata.x.nodes(
    '//parameters'
  ) as pp(p)
cross apply (
  values(
    cast(pp.p.value(
      '.', 'nvarchar(max)'
    ) as xml)
   )
  ) as xp(p)
cross apply
  xp.p.nodes('//value') as xv(v);
```

## Update #2:

You can get more detail information about working in Sql Server with XML data in the "[XQuery Language Reference (SQL Server)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-language-reference-sql-server?view=sql-server-2016)".
There are two articles on the [`CROSS`](https://sqlity.net/en/1270/a-join-a-day-the-cross-apply/) and [`OUTER`](https://sqlity.net/en/1275/a-join-a-day-the-outer-apply/) [`APPLY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#using-apply) operators with examples of their application to XML data.

```
select
  replace(xv.v.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)'), '|', '') as cdata,
  xci.ci.value('(//serialNumber)[1]', 'nvarchar(15)') as sn,
  xci.ci.value('(entries/entry/endUser)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as eu,
  xci.ci.value('(entries/entry/name)[1]', 'nvarchar(50)') as name
from dbo.cdata
cross apply
  cdata.x.nodes('/CatalogItem') as xci(ci)
outer apply
  xci.ci.nodes('parameters') as pp(p)
outer apply (
  values(
    cast(pp.p.value(
      '.', 'nvarchar(max)'
    ) as xml)
   )
  ) as xp(p)
outer apply
  xp.p.nodes('//value') as xv(v);
```

## Output:

```
+-----------+--------+------------------+--------+
|   cdata   |   sn   |        eu        |  name  |
+-----------+--------+------------------+--------+
| gdefgd    | zsxxdx | farhad@drf.local | NULL   |
| foo       | zsxxdx | farhad@drf.local | NULL   |
| gdefgd170 | zsxxdx | farhad@drf.local | NULL   |
| foo170    | zsxxdx | farhad@drf.local | NULL   |
| NULL      | foobar | user@mail.net    | NULL   |
| NULL      | NULL   | NULL             | farhad |
+-----------+--------+------------------+--------+
```

Test it online with [Rextester](https://rextester.com/VKO8400).

Comment: thanks a lot. can i extract CDATA from all values of XML row?

Comment: Could you provide more test data?

Comment: what do you need?

Comment: i can give you TeamViewer. is it ok?

Comment: TeamViewer? No, thanks :) In your test data, I see only one `CDATA` section. How will the data look if there is more than one `CDATA` section? I made a guess about this and updated my answer.

Comment: there is column with 512 rows and i want to extract CDATA of all of them. there is only one entry in each row.

Comment: Thanks for clarifications. Check out my updated answer.

Comment: Thanks A Lot.
insert into dbo.cdata(x)
  values ('x')
can i replace 'x' with select query?

Comment: Look at [Using the SELECT and EXECUTE options to insert data from other tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016#h-using-the-select-and-execute-options-to-insert-data-from-other-tables).

Comment: i am so sorry but i have another question.is there any way to remove '||' from output data?

Comment: To remove all occurrences of the `|` character, use the [REPLACE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/replace-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2016) function.

Comment: Well, ask your question.

Comment: thank you, i run new query but 'sn' and 'eu' columns are NULL

Comment: i think i found problem. the query will work if three parameters (CDATA, SerialNumber and EndUser) exists in XML file but in some XML only exist CDATA and in some other Serial Number and EndUser (together) exist.

Comment: yes it's works. excuse me, i am so so sorry. this is my last questions, i promise you. is it possible to extract 'name' (<entries> <entry> <name>farhad</name>) tag?

Comment: i never forget your help.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

Comment: do you have a time to look at this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56471512/extract-xml-tag-data-from-xml-column-in-mssql

Comment: Did @Shnugo answer your question?

Comment: sorry for asking another question. if i have multiple name tags in Update 3 XML, the query only return first of them. is it possible to query return all of them?

Comment: like always perfect. can i set name for (No column name) column?

Comment: Do you need a [column_alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2012/ms176104%28v%3dsql.110%29)?