# Extract xml tag data from XML column in MSSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

like my previous question, i want to extract all "name" and path tags (privilegedUsers --> entries --> entry --> name) by sql query. 
thanx

```
<Policy>
 <id>f3d25685-fb54-438d-a0e9-03e4ba5b555f</id>
 <name>SG</name>
 <description />
 <attributes>0</attributes>
 <parentPolicy>a7c603c0-8700-45ef-9165-c0134e292ee4</parentPolicy>
 <sharedPasswordRev>-1</sharedPasswordRev>
 <useShortChallengeResponse>false</useShortChallengeResponse>
 <settings>
 <privilegedUsers>
 <entries>
  <entry>
   <name>CEO</name>
   <path>CN=CEO,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
   <uid>27C9C6AC9311424BB332CC5AB04B047D</uid>
   <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
   <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-1108</sid>
   <type>user</type>
 </entry>
 <entry>
    <name>Administrator</name>
    <path>CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
    <uid>EBBC4D71CD68BE4BA49BC8B6DF01F954</uid>
    <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
    <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-500</sid>
    <type>user</type>
   </entry>
 </privilegedUsers>
 <unknownAppsStrategy>EDITOR</unknownAppsStrategy>
</settings>
</Policy>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<Policy>
 <id>f3d25685-fb54-438d-a0e9-03e4ba5b555f</id>
 <name>SG</name>
 <description />
 <attributes>0</attributes>
 <parentPolicy>a7c603c0-8700-45ef-9165-c0134e292ee4</parentPolicy>
 <sharedPasswordRev>-1</sharedPasswordRev>
 <useShortChallengeResponse>false</useShortChallengeResponse>
 <settings>
 <privilegedUsers>
 <entries>
  <entry>
   <name>CEO</name>
   <path>CN=CEO,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
   <uid>27C9C6AC9311424BB332CC5AB04B047D</uid>
   <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
   <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-1108</sid>
   <type>user</type>
 </entry>
 <entry>
    <name>Administrator</name>
    <path>CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
    <uid>EBBC4D71CD68BE4BA49BC8B6DF01F954</uid>
    <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
    <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-500</sid>
    <type>user</type>
   </entry>
 </entries>
 </privilegedUsers>
 <unknownAppsStrategy>EDITOR</unknownAppsStrategy>
</settings>
</Policy>';
```

--The query

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Policy/id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS id
      ,@xml.value('(/Policy/name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [name]
      --Use similar lines for all the other values below `<Policy>`
      ,prUsrEntry.value('(name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PrivilegedUserName
      ,prUsrEntry.value('(path/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PrivilegedUserpath
      --Use similar lines for values within the given `<entry>`
FROM @xml.nodes('/Policy/settings/privilegedUsers/entries/entry') A(prUsrEntry);
```

The idea in short:

We use direct calls to `.value()` to retrieve the *first-level-properties* directly from `@xml`. It is possible and a bit easier to read to use `nodes()` or `.query()` to avoid the repeated XPath, but this would be worse in performance.

Then we use `FROM @xml.nodes()` to get a derived table of repeating elements. Each `<entry>` at the given path will be returned as a row in a derived table with a XML-typed column representing the `<entry>` at this path.

Wen can now use `.value()` to read the nested elements. Be aware of the *relative path* (no `/` before `name`).

Some hints:

Your XML looks, as if it might contain several different `<settings>`. You can use a query like this, to be more generic:

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Policy/id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS id
      ,@xml.value('(/Policy/name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [name]
      --Use similar lines for all the other values below `<Policy>`
      ,prUsrEntry.value('(name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PrivilegedUserName
      ,prUsrEntry.value('(path/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PrivilegedUserpath
      --Use similar lines for values within the given `<entry>`
FROM @xml.nodes('/Policy/settings') A(settings)
OUTER APPLY A.settings.nodes('privilegedUsers/entries/entry') B(prUsrEntry)
--Add more APPLYs to fetch values from other `<settings>` areas
```

Or even something allong this totally generic approach

```
SELECT @xml.value('(/Policy/id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS id
      ,@xml.value('(/Policy/name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [name]
      --Use similar lines for all the other values below `<Policy>`
      ,anySeeting.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS SettingName
      ,anyValue.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS ValueName
      ,anyValue.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS NestedValue
FROM @xml.nodes('/Policy/settings') A(settings)
OUTER APPLY A.settings.nodes('*') B(anySeeting)
OUTER APPLY B.anySeeting.nodes('entries/entry/*') AS C(anyValue)
```

### UPDATE

This is the way to do the same against table data:

```
SELECT YourXML.value('(/Policy/id/text())[1]','uniqueidentifier') AS id
      ,YourXML.value('(/Policy/name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS [name]
      --Use similar lines for all the other values below `<Policy>`
      ,prUsrEntry.value('(name/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PrivilegedUserName
      ,prUsrEntry.value('(path/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS PrivilegedUserpath
      --Use similar lines for values within the given `<entry>`
FROM YourTable
OUTER APPLY YourXML.nodes('/Policy/settings/privilegedUsers/entries/entry') A(prUsrEntry);
```

Comment: thanks a lot. i have column name "XML" that stored xml files. i want to extract name and path from all of them. can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

Your xml is not well formed. You have no closing `</entries>` tag.

When I fix  that, this is your code:

```
declare @xml xml
set @xml=convert(xml,'<Policy>
 <id>f3d25685-fb54-438d-a0e9-03e4ba5b555f</id>
 <name>SG</name>
 <description />
 <attributes>0</attributes>
 <parentPolicy>a7c603c0-8700-45ef-9165-c0134e292ee4</parentPolicy>
 <sharedPasswordRev>-1</sharedPasswordRev>
 <useShortChallengeResponse>false</useShortChallengeResponse>
 <settings>
 <privilegedUsers>
 <entries>
  <entry>
   <name>CEO</name>
   <path>CN=CEO,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
   <uid>27C9C6AC9311424BB332CC5AB04B047D</uid>
   <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
   <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-1108</sid>
   <type>user</type>
 </entry>
 <entry>
    <name>Administrator</name>
    <path>CN=Administrator,CN=Users,DC=sglab,DC=local</path>
    <uid>EBBC4D71CD68BE4BA49BC8B6DF01F954</uid>
    <serverName>192.168.7.201</serverName>
    <sid>S-1-5-21-3362085216-3357124804-2073486349-500</sid>
    <type>user</type>
   </entry>
   </entries>
 </privilegedUsers>
 <unknownAppsStrategy>EDITOR</unknownAppsStrategy>
</settings>
</Policy>')

select @xml.query('/Policy/settings/privilegedUsers/entries/entry/name')
```

Comment: thank you. is it possible to extract every name in single row?